# RDLC with Subreport fails with upgrade from 8.0 to 10.0

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, subreport

I have a report that I run in an ASP.NET application using the ReportViewer.Common and ReportViewer.Webforms.  With the 2005 version (8.0.0.0) of the RDL file (renamed to RDLC), it worked fine in my ASP.NET web app.  After upgrading the report to 2008 (10.0.0.0), my report no longer works.

Error is quite extensive, but ends with:

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.AbortHelper.ThrowAbortException(String reportUniqueName)
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.CheckAndThrowIfAborted()
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RetrievalManager.FetchData(Boolean mergeTran
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RetrievalManager.PrefetchData(ReportInstance reportInstance, ParameterInfoCollection parameters, Boolean mergeTran)

What I have done:

I have checked and all parameters for the report are being set.

I set all the data sources with valid DataTable objects.  I've checked all the columns are present in my DataTable.

I have a SubReportProcessing event handler setup.  The processing steps into this function and I set the necessary DataTable in that function with valid data.  This works for each call to the subreport.

Unfortunately, the Report with subreport works fine in the BI Dev Studio.  Go figure.

I can .LocalReport.Render() and get an Exception thrown, but the error is really deep in the .NET reporting engine, as described above.

I realize most would say I am missing a parameter.  I could be.

How can I debug this report AFTER the subreport datasets have been supplied?  Is there some level of tracing I can enable to get more out of the rendering engine?

Another question is:  Is there a way to control the timeout of the SubReport Render?  I have set the report script manager to 900 seconds (way high).

Thank you in advance for any guidance you might have on debugging this problem.

Dan

Dan.Zemmels@zcsi.net